# How to assign role to an Azure service principal from different subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

**problem statement** 
currently, I am in the process to create/modify azure resources in the different subscription with the help of azure terraform.

**error**

```
Principal <appid> does not exist in the directory {destination-tenant-id-for which contribution role required}
```

**consider the following scenario.** 
we want to create Azure AKS cluster in one subscription and in same execution, we want to update DNS define in another subscription. this process works well if we are having both i.e. DNS zone and aks cluster in the same subscription but it will not work if these two resources in the different subscription.

**steps taken**
*create service principal without assignment*

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n sp-terraform-001 --skip-assignment
```

*assign contributor role for current sp for current subscription*

```
az role assignment create --assignee <appid>  --role Contributor --scope /subscriptions/<sub-id>
```

*assign contributor role to current sp for a different subscription. it will fail with *

```
az role assignment create --assignee <appid>  --role Contributor --scope /subscriptions/<diff-sub-id>/<resource-group>....
```

please let me know correct steps to access resources in another subscriptions

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Are these subscriptions in the same Azure AD tenant?

Comment: both of these subscriptions in a different tenant id. i am getting error like Principal <appid> does not exist in the directory <destination-tenant-id-for which contribution role required>. as per this error, i assume I need to add newly created SP in destination subscription

Answer (score 6):

You can assign rights to a service principal to multiple subscriptions, that is not an issue, as the SP sits outside of the subscription, it is in Azure AD.

However, you cannot assign rights to resources in a different Azure AD tenant to the one the service principal sits in, which it sounds like you are trying to do here.

Comment: This is correct, you need to make sure you create the SP in the right tenant.

Comment: As per my understanding in aws we are having concept like trust relationship. Which enable role access across different aws account. Don’t we have similar concept in azure.

Comment: No, there is not currently an ability to have service principals access another tenant. You can do it with users as guests, but not SPs