# terraform resource deployment across multiple subscription using service principle

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I have a single Service principle. Since my terraform code needs to access resources present in subscription A and B, how do i perform that, below is my provider block.

```
 provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
    }
provider "azurerm" {
  alias   = "vnet"
  subscription_id = "0000"
  features {}
   }
data "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "foo" {
  provider            = azurerm.vnet
  name                = var.private_dnszonename
  resource_group_name = var.existing_dnsresourcegroup
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow us to create resources in multiple subscriptions, you could use multiple AzureRM providers by using **aliases**. You could also define SP authentication in your provider blocks. Then you can declare your resources in the specific provider.

For example, to create a resource group in that subscription with alias `vnet` azurerm provider.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  provider = "azurerm.vnet"
  name     = var.rgname                   
  location = var.location  
}
```

Read more details [here](https://azurecitadel.com/automation/terraform/lab5/).

Comment: i have done the same as you mentioned above but terraform plan throws and  Error ensuring Resource Providers are registered.More information on the "skip_provider_registration" flag can be found here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html#skip_provider_registration.

Comment: do i need 2service principals or having a single sp with contributor access on both subscription will work. also i have added the code,

Comment: You can either create service principal per subscription or one SP has rights on both subscriptions, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522416/how-to-assign-role-to-an-azure-service-principal-from-different-subscription). Different service principals can have different scopes and roles within a subscription.

Comment: actually the issue was not with the SP having role on both subscription but the error was terraform was trying to register the provider. I added the skip_provider
_registration flag as true and i was able to deploy

Comment: I thought I have a bit confused about your question. So, does your original question been resolved instead of a question in the comment?

Comment: yes the original question was resolved with the flag thing and it answers both the question. Earlier i though it might be SP role issues but turned out to be not

Comment: I have upvoted the useful comments. If the issue is fixed, you may consider accepting it for other people's reference.